# Is it possible to change a lexical scope programmatically, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope

I don't know if that is even possible but, say we have the following code :

```
var name = 'John';

function log() {
    console.log('Hello ' + name );
}

function greetTravis() {
    var name = 'Travis';

    log(); // This function is defined outside greetTravis's scope. 
}


greetTravis();
log();
```

**Result :**

```
Hello John // Is there a workaround to get "Hello Travis"?
Hello John
```

**A hard-coded solution :** (I don't wanna repeat myself)

```
var name = 'John';

function log() {
    console.log('Hello ' + name );
}

function greetTravis() {
    var name = 'Travis';

    log(); // Now, it is defined inside greetTravis's scope. 

    function log() {
        console.log('Hello ' + name );
    }

}


greetTravis();
log();
```

**What I'm after :**

I'd like to access the name variable (the one inside greetTravis() ) from the log function without passing a variable, maybe using a function that changes the scope of log(), something like: call/bind .

> **Note:** call and bind functions allow you to change the **context** (this) **not** the **scope** .

Comment: I have problems to understand what you want to do. Can you explain it better please

Comment: It's not that `log` is declared outside of `greetTravis` scope, it's that the reference inside the `log` function is to the global variable `name`, not the `name` variable inside of `greetTravis`

Comment: a workaround you're looking for is to pass a variable into log.

Comment: Just send it as an argument like PerrinPrograms said.

Comment: @PerrinPrograms I'd like to access it without passing a variable, maybe use a function that changes the scope of log() [something like: call/bind ]

Comment: I am not sure if it does what you want so I am leaving it as a comment here but you can add log to the prototype of your other function and use `.bind` to change the context of a specific call.

Comment: I don't understand. How is `log.call(someContext)` better than the super simple and straightforward `log(variable)`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It makes a difference if you need many variables from the context. So you dont have to pass, e.g. 10 variables to the log function.

Comment: @Marie I don't see how that's useful either. Having a function that depends on the context variables names is far worst than passing a bunch of variables to it. Also the valiables could be handled as a list, either by using the `arguments` object or by the rest syntax `...args`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer :** Yes you can :-D, but it's not recommended though .

**Long answer :** 
In Javascript, The lexical scope is defined by where a function declaration is written in the code,
and in order to modify the lexical scope at run-time, you should use the [eval function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) ( even though it's going to **slightly reduce** the **performance** ) as follows:

```
var name = 'John';

function log() {
    console.log('Hello ' + name );
}
function greetTravis() {
    var name = 'Travis';

    eval( log.toString() ); // <==== The added code.

    log();

}

greetTravis();
log();
```

In this case, using eval() is completely safe ( **[eval() isn’t evil](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)** ).

Comment: The author of the article on `eval()` that you link to is just wrong in his argument. If you do fully understand `eval()`, then you understand that whenever you find yourself in a coding corner that you can only get out of by using `eval()`, you've probably thought about the coding problem incorrectly. `eval()` has nothing but down sides and in all but the most specific of use cases, can be completely avoided in the first place - - and should be.

Answer (score 2):

For the result you want, you would simply refactor `log` so that it takes the name you want it to log.

FYI - The `window` object has a property called `name`. So, it's a best-practice to not use `name` as a Global in your code.

```js
var userName = 'John';

function log(val) {
    console.log('Hello ' + val );
}

function greetTravis() {
    var userName = 'Travis';

    log(userName); // This function is defined outside greetTravis's scope. 
}


greetTravis();
log(userName);
```

Comment: I'd like to access it without passing a variable, maybe use a function that changes the scope of log() [something like: call/bind ]

Answer (score 2):

Not anything as simple, I think.

If you didn't use `var name = 'Travis';` inside greetTravis, you'd be overwriting the global value, but then, when `log();` is called the second time, it would also log `Hello Travis`.

I think what you want is something like

```
function createPersonObj(name) {
    return { // this must be on the same line
        name: name
    }
}

var name = 'John';
var personJohn = createPersonObj(name);

function log() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name );
}

function greetTravis() {
    var name = 'Travis';
    var personTravis = createPersonObj(name);

    log.call(personTravis);
}

greetTravis();
log.call(personJohn);
```

Without making John an object, you could instead check for `this.name` inside `log()`, and if exists, use it, otherwise, use `name`

```
function log() {
    var nameToLog = (this.name !== undefined)
        ? this.name
        : name;
    console.log('Hello ' + nameToLog );
}
```

Source: https://www.codementor.io/niladrisekhardutta/how-to-call-apply-and-bind-in-javascript-8i1jca6jp

> Check the code sample below for call()
>
> ```
> //Demo with javascript .call()
>
> var obj = {name:"Niladri"};
>
> var greeting = function(a,b,c){
>     return "welcome "+this.name+" to "+a+" "+b+" in "+c;
> };
>
> console.log(greeting.call(obj,"Newtown","KOLKATA","WB"));
> // returns output as welcome Niladri to Newtown KOLKATA in WB
> ```
>
> The first parameter in call() method sets the "this" value, which is the object, on which the function is invoked upon. In this case, it's the "obj" object above.
>
> The rest of the parameters are the arguments to the actual function.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the log() function only has access to the global variable name. In order for it to render the local variable, you would need to get "name" by parameter